# Finding the Moment Generating function of a Binomial Distribution

Tags: statistics, summation, generating-functions, binomial-theorem, moment-generating-functions

Suppose $X$ has a $\rm{Binomial}(n,p)$ distribution. Then its moment generating function is

> \begin{align}
> M(t)
> &= \sum_{x=0}^x e^{xt}{n \choose x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x} \\
> &=\sum_{x=0}^{n} {n \choose x}(pe^t)^x(1-p)^{n-x} \\
> &=(pe^t+1-p)^n
> \end{align}

Can someone please explain how the sum is obtained from lines (2) to (3)?

Comment: This is the [Binomial formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).

Comment: It makes sense to me that the Binomial Theorem would be applied to this, I'm just having a hard time working out how they get to the final result using it :\

Comment: It all makes sense now, it "is" a syntactically simplified way to write the Binomial Theorem. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: Call $l=pe^t$ and $j=1-p$, then the second line is $\sum_{x=0}^n {n \choose x} l^x j^{n-x} = (l+j)^n$ by the binomial formula.

Comment: this video explains how to find the mgf of a binomial distribution: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XEm3lzquu5c

Comment: You are missing an $e^{tx}$ in the first line.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [moment generating function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) for the binomial distribution $B_{n,p}$, whose discrete density is $\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$, is defined as
$$
\begin{align}
M_{B_{n,p}}(t)
&=\mathrm{E}(e^{tk})\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}e^{tk}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(pe^t\right)^k(1-p)^{n-k}\\
&=\left(pe^t+(1-p)\right)^n
\end{align}
$$
The last step is simply an application of the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @krngrvr09 's response:

Because Bernoulli is a special case of Binomial distribution, PMF of binomial distribution $$\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$ can be rewritten as $$\binom{1}{0}p^1(1-p)^{1-0}$$

Thus, we can get the following for each instance of $X$ for $X \sim Bin(n,p)$ and $X = \sum^n_{j=1}X_j$
$$ 
\begin{array}
  \mathbb{E}[e^{tX_j}] & = \sum^n_{k=0}e^{tk}\binom{1}{0}p^1(1-p)^{1-0} \\
                      & = (pe^t +1 -p)^1 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{by Binomial Theorem}\\
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score -2):

$\phi(t) = \mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]
       \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}[e^{t\cdot(\Sigma x)}]
       \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}[e^{tx_1}\cdot e^{tx_2}\cdot...\cdot e^{tx_n}]
       \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}[e^{tx_1}]\cdot \mathbb{E}[e^{tx_2}]\cdot...\cdot \mathbb{E}[e^{tx_n}]$

Since all individual events are independent,
$\Rightarrow [pe^t + (1-p)].[pe^t + (1-p)].[pe^t + (1-p)]...[pe^t + (1-p)]$ n times, since all n random variables are Bernoulli random variables
$\Rightarrow[pe^t + (1-p)]^n=[pe^t + q]^n$, where $q=1-p$.